# "TypeError: tensor is not a torch image" appears sometimes when code modified, and disappears after I run the code again

Tags: python, pycharm, pytorch

I am learning how to use Pytorch following the official tutorial: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html

Everything went smoothly until I ran the CIFAR10 classification example.(I didn't modify the code at all)

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/pycharm_project_331/main.py", line 90, in <module>
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 286, in __next__
    return self._process_next_batch(batch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 307, in _process_next_batch
    raise batch.exc_type(batch.exc_msg)
TypeError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 57, in _worker_loop
    samples = collate_fn([dataset[i] for i in batch_indices])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 57, in <listcomp>
    samples = collate_fn([dataset[i] for i in batch_indices])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torchvision/datasets/cifar.py", line 121, in __getitem__
    img = self.transform(img)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py", line 49, in __call__
    img = t(img)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py", line 143, in __call__
    return F.normalize(tensor, self.mean, self.std)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional.py", line 165, in normalize
    raise TypeError('tensor is not a torch image.')
TypeError: tensor is not a torch image.
```

I thought maybe I miss some codes, but the code is fine. So I ran the code again for a few more times. The error message disappear somehow, and the training went smoothly.

I can't find any pattern to replicate the error. It just pops up whenever I change the code, and fixed itself without any code modification.

I configured PyCharm to connect to a remote interpreters via SSH(an Ubuntu server), but the same thing occurred when I'm using a local interpreter, and running the code via python console.

This is so frustrating since I have no idea if my code is wrong or it's just the same thing happening.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have modified your code and that's why the error occurs.

Problem lies in the `ToTensor` transformation from `torchvision`, this fragment specifically:

```
transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])
```

You need to transform `PIL` image to `torch.Tensor` object in order to normalize it. If you remove `transforms.ToTensor()` you are left with the above error.

Comment: Thank you for leaving a comment here. I'm completely honest that I didn't modify my code between an error run and an error-free run. The only thing I did is to click the "run" button.

Comment: I know, but this error occurs if you do not cast PIL image to tensor. Comment `ToTensor` and you'll see exact same error.

Comment: You're right! However, I still don't understand why running the same code again can solve the error.

Comment: Can you run the code at least once without `ToTensor()`? Does it ever fail with this function in place? I suspect you accidentally deleted that line and that's how this error came to live.